# Display fields/datasets depending on attributes

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I want to display those that have attributes then..

- If it has "Update" attribute, it will only display elements and datasets with "Add", "Prior" or "Update" attributes under it.
- If with "Add" attribute, then it will display all elements and datasets regardless if with attributes or none.

**INPUT**

```
<Elements>
    <Element>
        <Entry1>
            <data attribute="Delete">value</data>
        </Entry1>
        <Entry2 attribute="Delete"/>
        <Entry3>
            <data attribute="Update">value</data>
        </Entry3>
    </Element>
    <Element2 attribute="Update">
        <Entry1>
            <data2>
                <data3 attribute="Delete">value</data3>       
            </data2>
        </Entry1>
        <Entry2 attribute="Add">value</Entry2>
        <Entry3>
            <data attribute="Update">value</data>
        </Entry3>       
        <Entry4 attribute="Prior">value</Entry4>
        <Entry5>value</Entry5>
        <Entry6 attribute="Add">
            <data>value</data>
            <data2>value</data2>
            <data3>value</data3>
        </Entry6>
        <Entry7 attribute="Update">
            <data>value</data>
            <data2 attribute="Add">value</data2>
            <data3>value</data3>
        </Entry7>
    </Element2>
    <Element3>
        <Entry1>
            <data attribute="Add">value</data>
        </Entry1>
    </Element3>
    <Element4 attribute="Add">
        <Entry1>
            <data>value</data>
        </Entry1>
        <Entry2>
            <data>value</data>
        </Entry2>
    </Element4>
    <Element5 attribute="Add">Value</Element5>
    <Element6 attribute="Update">Value</Element6>
</Elements>
```

**DESIRED OUTPUT**

```
<Elements>
    <Element2 attribute="Update">
        <Entry2 attribute="Add">value</Entry2>
        <Entry4 attribute="Prior">value</Entry4>
        <Entry6 attribute="Add">
            <data>value</data>
            <data2>value</data2>
            <data3>value</data3>
        </Entry6>
        <Entry7 attribute="Update">
            <data2 attribute="Add">value</data2>
        </Entry7>
    </Element2>
    <Element4 attribute="Add">
        <Entry1>
            <data>value</data>
        </Entry1>
        <Entry2>
            <data>value</data>
        </Entry2>
    </Element4>
    <Element5 attribute="Add">Value</Element5>
    <Element6 attribute="Update">Value</Element6>
</Elements>
```

I'm using below XSLT. However, it's still displaying all fields (even those that do not have flags) on some datasets with "Update" attributes. See Element2 > Entry1, Entry3, Entry5 and Element2 > Entry7 > data, data3

What am I missing?

**XSLT**

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Elements">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | *[@attribute='Update'] | *[@attribute='Add'] | *[@attribute='Prior'] "/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

**ACTUAL OUTPUT**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Elements>
    <Element2 attribute="Update">
        <Entry1>
            <data2>
                <data3 attribute="Delete">value</data3>       
            </data2>
        </Entry1>
        <Entry2 attribute="Add">value</Entry2>
        <Entry3>
            <data attribute="Update">value</data>
        </Entry3>       
        <Entry4 attribute="Prior">value</Entry4>
        <Entry5>value</Entry5>
        <Entry6 attribute="Add">
            <data>value</data>
            <data2>value</data2>
            <data3>value</data3>
        </Entry6>
        <Entry7 attribute="Update">
            <data>value</data>
            <data2 attribute="Add">value</data2>
            <data3>value</data3>
        </Entry7>
    </Element2>
    <Element4 attribute="Add">
        <Entry1>
            <data>value</data>
        </Entry1>
        <Entry2>
            <data>value</data>
        </Entry2>
    </Element4>
    <Element5 attribute="Add">Value</Element5>
    <Element6 attribute="Update">Value</Element6>
</Elements>
```

Comment: *"What am I missing?"* You are missing the fact that your template matches `Elements` and therefore the conditions are applied only to elements that are children of the root `Elements` element and not to its other descendants. Unfortunately I cannot tell you how to fix this because I do not understand the logic that you want to apply here. I presume those element names are just an example - and it seems there are different rules for each level.